# Override pipe when testing component

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing

I am trying to unit test a component that uses custom pipe. I want to provide a fake implementation of `transform` method for my test.

I have found that it is possible to [override](https://angular.io/guide/testing#more-overrides) components, modules, pipe, etc., but I don't see how it is possible to override the behavior (implementation) of component.

I have tried to provide me custom class as a replacement for pipe and it didn't work:

```
TestBed
  .configureTestingModule({declarations: [MyPipe]})
  .overridePipe(MDatePipe, {set: MyFakePipe})
```

I have found similar question on SO [How to mock Pipe when testing Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293258/how-to-mock-pipe-when-testing-component), but suggested solution was to create complete new pipe and provide it to `declarations` of testing module which is a bit too much in my opinion.

If `overridePipe` won't allow me to override `transform` implementation would it be possible to get instance of created `MyPipe` class and `spyOn` it?

```
var pipe = TestBed.get(MyPipe);
```

didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a way to override the behavior of the Pipe so I ended up providing fake service to the real Pipe so that I can mock it's behavior.

Alternative solution would be to create fake pipe implementation for the test as suggested in answer to question [How to mock Pipe when testing Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293258/how-to-mock-pipe-when-testing-component).

Comment: Still any ideas how to do this? =)

Comment: @SharikovVladislav, that's basically how I did. My Pipe uses service and I fake the service to define behavior of the Pipe. Alternative solution during my research was to create a fake pipe in the test and register it with the same name. Which might also work well, but requires a bit more work.

Comment: I tried this: `Alternative solution during my research was to create a fake pipe in the test and register it with the same name`. That does not work.

Comment: Here is what I tried: https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/ng2-diary-book/pull/41/commits/923f766185aaf977fe27b87f7a0ae72f11b84911. And here you can find red CI build: https://circleci.com/gh/sharikovvladislav/ng2-diary-book/103?utm_campaign=vcs-integration-link&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=github-build-link. I still get wrong timezone.

Comment: I also tried to mock whole components and used `overrideComponent` method. I got the idea: I can change metadata of inner angular DatePipe. I can change name and I can load my own FakeDatePipe. Perhaps this will work. I will try a bit later.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav solution you referenced does not sound quite right. I think you should do create your own `FakeDatePipe`. I have updated my answer with a link to another answer.